# Why does Flask is receiving this variable as unicode but not as array?

Tags: python, jquery, arrays, post, flask

I trying to send an array by Post Method using Jquery.

```
function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default, if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}

var url = "{{url_for('page')}}";
post_to_url(url,{'data':arrayObj}, "post");
```

Until here, when I use `console.log($.type(arrayObj))`, is returning me an array.

```
@mod.route('/page',methods=["POST","GET"])
def page():
 if request.method=="POST":
  import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
  d = request.form['data']
  return render_template('testing/page.html',data=d)
 return render_template('testing/page.html')
```

Using PDB, `type(d)` the variable is returning an unicode. Why?

Answer (score 1):

`params` has a single key. The for loop is executed once, and this line:

```
hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
```

… is setting the hidden field value to the array serialized to a string.

If you know all your keys are array objects, just loop over the values and insert multiple input elements:

```
for (let key in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        let values = params[key];
        for (let value of values) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", value);
            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't know all your keys are arrays, you can change the backend code to split incoming values on comma. Note this will break for any values that literally contain `,`.

```
@mod.route('/page',methods=["POST","GET"])
def page():
 if request.method=="POST":
  d = request.form['data']
  d_array = d.split(',')
  return render_template('testing/page.html',data=d_array)
 return render_template('testing/page.html')
```

Comment: Printing `document.body.appendChild(form);` it's creating one input hidden and storing all the array values in value field, like `<input type="hidden" name="data" value="1,234,567,adsa,sadasf,23432,32432">`

Comment: Precisely. If you want an array on the Flask side, you must either parse your singular input using something like `str.split`, or your frontend script needs to create `n` hidden inputs for each `n` items in the array.

Comment: Can you show me? I was trying, but without success!

Comment: Updated to show looping on front-end or split on back-end.

Comment: Weird, it  just is returning the first position, When I print form.appendChild, returns only one value